# Create an input prompt for an integer

Tags: python

Hi I am a beginner for python. May I ask how do you write an input prompt that takes a single number as the input, which represents a new row. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, you can use input() to read the input from the keyboard so if you want to use it later you can use a variable to store the input

```
str_input = input("Enter the string")
```

so by using the variable str_input you can get the value for later use like for printing etc. for print the value use

```
print(str_input)
```

So if you need to read the number as input then you need to typecast because everything in python default as a string so for typecast use

```
num_int = int(input("Enter the number"))
```

So by this you can read the num